# How to remove a directory symlink without breaking files that depend on it?

Tags: linux, directory, symlink

For the sake of simplicity, suppose the following situation, where *folder* is a symlink to *new_folder*:

```
.
├── folder -> new_folder/
├── new_folder
│   └── test.sh
└── exectest.sh
```

The contents of *test.sh* are:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
echo 'test'
```

The contents of *exectest.sh* are:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
echo 'executing test'
./folder/test.sh
```

If I run `./exectest.sh`, the output is as expected:

```
executing test
test
```

Now let's suppose I want to remove *folder*, so I'll do `unlink folder`. But if I run `./exectest.sh`, it'll throw an error:

```
executing test
./exectest.sh: line 3: ./folder/test.sh: No such file or directory
```

So my question is: how to remove *folder* without breaking *exectest.sh*?

---

If that matters, something similar is happening with my user folder: when I bought this computer, the *~* directory was */home/user/*. After a while, I decided to change it to */home/new_user/*. As in that period I had installed some programs that depended on */home/user/*, I created a symlink called */home/user/* pointing to */home/new_user/*. Now I want to remove */home/user/* and keep only */home/new_user/*, but it will break some files that still depend on it.

What to do in this situation? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There's no easy answer to this.

You're going to have to search through all the files that refer to `/home/user` (or `folder`) and hope that they're editable and can be changed to `/home/new_user` (or `new_folder`).

Comment: What a pity... Do you think something like `sed -i 's-/home/user-/home/new_user-g' /home/new_user/*` could solve the problem?

Comment: It might. But it could also irretrievably corrupt non-text database files so beloved of subsystems like Gnome.